# How to hide mouse cursor in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
class ExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExampleWidget> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<ExampleWidget> {
  bool showCursor = false;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MouseRegion(
      cursor: showCursor ? SystemMouseCursors.basic : SystemMouseCursors.none,
    );
  }
}
```

In the above code, on Windows, a mouse cursor will be hidden if `showCursor` is set to `false` **and the user moves his cursor**. If value of `showCursor` is set to false, while user is not moving his mouse, the cursor icon **will not be updated** until the user moves it.

This is due to a bug in the Flutter engine: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76622.

How can I workaround this issue? Is there some alternative way to hide the mouse cursor in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to find a workaround to this issue:

```dart
import 'package:win32/win32.dart';
import 'package:win32/win32.dart' as win32;
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';

Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
    Pointer<POINT> point = malloc();
    win32.GetCursorPos(point);
    win32.SetCursorPos(point.ref.x, point.ref.y);
    free(point);
});
```

Just call this after you change the `cursor`.

This code will call a `win32` API to manually update mouse position (which will trigger a cursor icon change). I also wrap it in a Timer, so the `MouseRegion` has time to react.

---

You might have to install `win32` and `ffi` pub packages.

---

I have also created a `EnhancedMouseRegion` which works the same as MouseRegion, but has this issue fixed:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:win32/win32.dart';
import 'package:win32/win32.dart' as win32;
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';

class EnhancedMouseRegion extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(PointerEnterEvent)? onEnter;
  final Function(PointerExitEvent)? onExit;
  final Function(PointerHoverEvent)? onHover;
  final MouseCursor cursor;
  final bool opaque;
  final HitTestBehavior? hitTestBehavior;
  final Widget? child;

  const EnhancedMouseRegion({
    super.key,
    this.onEnter,
    this.onExit,
    this.onHover,
    this.cursor = MouseCursor.defer,
    this.opaque = true,
    this.hitTestBehavior,
    this.child,
  });

  @override
  State<EnhancedMouseRegion> createState() => _EnhancedMouseRegionState();
}

class _EnhancedMouseRegionState extends State<EnhancedMouseRegion> {
  MouseCursor? lastCursor;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (lastCursor != widget.cursor) {
      Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
        Pointer<POINT> point = malloc();
        win32.GetCursorPos(point);
        win32.SetCursorPos(point.ref.x, point.ref.y);
        free(point);
      });
    }
    lastCursor = widget.cursor;
    
    return MouseRegion(
      onEnter: widget.onEnter,
      onExit: widget.onExit,
      onHover: widget.onHover,
      cursor: widget.cursor,
      opaque: widget.opaque,
      hitTestBehavior: widget.hitTestBehavior,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```